# Change Domain.com/shop to domain.com

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently bought a .Shop domain name, Installed Wordpress then Woocommerce. The issue is that when i install the Woocommerce plugin it automatically creates a products page on my site with the following URL: Domain.shop/SHOP, I want the products page to be the homepage of the site which is Domain.shop and not domain.shop/SHOP.

So now the main domain Domain.shop only shows articles list like: (Hello world)

And the actual shop is at Domain.shop/SHOP

I want the shop or the products list to be at the homepage not the /Shop page.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in as admin then go to the Dashboard > Settings > Reading page

In the **Front page displays** section

Select the **A static page** radio button.

For the **Front page:** select **Shop**

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery and do the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.location(“/shop”);
})
```

This won’t actually set it as the home page but it will just redirect you to the shop when the page loads. To set it as the home page you will have to make an app.js and make a server using node.js and express and create custom extensions

Comment: Too much stuff to do for a begginer :(

Comment: Not if you have the drive to do it. One week ago I knew absolutely 0 JavaScript. Now I can build an entire web application using node.js

Comment: This solution is not ideal as the home page is served by the server, not used and then the server serves the shop page so it unnecessarily loads the server and takes twice as much time to load the shop page. Regarding your comment 'To set it as the home page you will have to...' this is not true.